# Will it be possible that implementing Clojure (or Clojure syntax) over SBCL(or Other fast Lisp)?

Tags: clojure, lisp, sbcl

I've tried both SBCL and Clojure and found that I like the syntax of Clojure but it is very slow compared to SBCL for me. Are there any implementation of Clojure over SBCL or will it be possible?

---

I found https://github.com/ayrnieu/disclojure which can enlighten me. :-)

Comment: Slower at run time or slower to start up? The runtime speed should be comparable, though the startup time is a known issue.

Comment: Which Clojure are you running? Perhaps you can edit in an example of something that is faster in SBCL than Clojure?

Comment: For a diverse set of small programs, SBCL does better on some, Clojure on others, under certain conditions: See [benchmark game](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=clojure&lang2=sbcl&data=u64q).  I personally think that SBCL is an incredible implementation.  Faster than any other Common Lisp for my main application.  Haven't tried porting it to Clojure.  Can't blame anyone for not liking CL's syntactic quirks.

Comment: @noisesmith My application is for analyzing stock quote data and on my slowest laptop (Core solo 1.3Mhz) it takes 7 secs to get a solution using SBCL, using Clojure it takes more than 14 secs. Yes, startup time itself might be another problem but I just run nrepl in Emacs and never turn it off so it's OK.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Clojure is intended to target several backends. This is a side effect Clojure being a hosted language designed with the [philosophy](http://clojure.org/rationale) of **embracing the host**. It will never be the goal, for instance, to make the same code written for Clojure on the JVM run unmodified on, again for instance, the CLR. Substantial amounts of code are common between Clojure for the JVM and ClojureScript, which is a nice bonus.

It is currently stable for:

- JVM
- JavaScript/ECMAScript

Generally stable for:

- CLR/.net

and I know of experimental builds for:

- Python
- C
- Scheme
- IOS (via Scheme)

More targets are showing up as interest and time intersect. If you would like to provide an implementation for your favorite Lisp, patches welcome! It would be advisable to base your implementation on the ClojureScript compiler as it best exemplifies the intended development methods for the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

While the previous answers stated the difficulties of hosting Clojure on different languages, there is one programming language which I think is interesting to look at: [Shen](http://shenlanguage.org/). It has been designed with a minimal set of [45 primitive instructions,](http://www.lambdassociates.org/specification/shen_1.8.htm#The%20Basic%20Types%20in%20Shen) so that it will be easy to port to different languages. It currently runs under CLisp, SBCL, Clojure, Scheme, Ruby, Python, Java and Javascript. It seems that it's a mix of ML and Lisp, although I haven't programmed with it much.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but its unlikly that you will get much faster, then it is on the JVM.

If you want to speed it up maybe look into the more highspeed librarys build for clojure, like clojure data using low level JVM representations and stuff like that or write your own librarys that are faster.

Making clojure fast on the JVM is tricky but doable, probebly a much better bet then a port to SBCL.